# Android JavaCV - UnsatisfiedLinkError and couldn't find "libopencv_core.so"

Tags: java, android, javacv

I use JavaCV 1.1. I have added jar files (javacv.jar, javacpp.jar and opencv.jar) and *.so libraries to my project in Android Studio. I succesfully build and run my app on Android 5.1 phone, but when i try use functions, that used OpenCV i get error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zipfile"/data/app/com.example.dogan.ligntningshower-/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopencv_core.so"
```

I try to add

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_core");
    System.loadLibrary("jniopencv_core");
}
```

but it's no work. How to fix it?

Comment: is the lib in the classpath/???

Comment: hm, what does it mean? sorry, i'm novice in android development

Answer (score 0):

I just add *.so libs to folder /app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi and now all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

if someone still looking for the answer, first you should check if you added correct files to `jniLibs` folders. heres a complete tutorial :
[A Beginner’s Guide to Setting up OpenCV Android Library on Android Studio](https://medium.com/android-news/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c)

second, if `.os` files are at their places in each and every folder then you should only change the names to the name that is showing up in the compiler error.
in my case the names were `libopencv_java3.so` and yet the compiler was saying  `couldn't find "libopencv_java343.so"`  . after changing the name to `libopencv_java343.so` it worked.